# Return the result of a SP while inside of a select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am wondering how to return the result of a SP inside of a select statement? I have multiple reports that need to use the same code I wrote in the SP where the contents of the SP may change 2-3 times a year.

The select statement would go something like this:

```
select Product, Cost, [Output from SP where input is Product Code] from table1
```

My stored procedure is meant to accept a 'Product Code' and then return a bucket type:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Product_Bucket_Type (@productcode nvarchar(4)= NULL, @bucket nvarchar(30) OUTPUT)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Select
    @bucket = Case
    WHEN @productcode IN ('20','22', '26','27','28','2A','2B') THEN 'CA'
    WHEN @productcode IN ('30','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','3A','3B','3C','3R') THEN 'NU' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('31','43') THEN 'Regulators' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('40','41','43A','43B','47','48','4A','4B','4F')THEN 'WH'
    WHEN @productcode IN ('50','57','58','5A','5B')THEN 'SN' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('90','97','98','99','9A','9B','9F') THEN 'QC'
    WHEN @productcode IN ('2J','B01','B02','B03','B04','B05','B06','B07','B08','B09','B10','B11','B12','B13','B14','B15','B16','B17','B23','B24','B25','B28','B29','B30') THEN 'BI' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('2R','2S','2W','B00','2SA','2SB','2SC','2SD','2SE','2SF','2SG','2SH','2SI','2SJ','2SK','2SL','2SM','2SN','2SO','2SP','2SQ','2SR','2SS','2ST','2SU','2SV','2H','2HA','2T','2TA','2TB','24C','2M') THEN 'TU' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('21','23','2G','2F','21A') THEN 'GA' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('2XA','2XB','2XC','2XD','2XE','2XF','2XG','2XH','2XI','2XJ','2XK','2XL','2XM','2XN','2XO','2XP','2XQ','Y0') THEN 'OU' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('Y7') THEN 'NC'       
    WHEN @productcode IN ('Y8') THEN 'CH' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('Y9') THEN 'CU' 
    WHEN @productcode IN ('Y1') THEN 'OU'    
    WHEN @productcode IN ('4P') THEN 'PR'
    ELSE 'OTHER'
    END
    if @productcode < '20' SET @bucket = 'SW'
END
GO
```

I am new to writing stored procedures so I am assuming my syntax for inputs and outputs is correct in the SP.

Comment: Use a function instead. `select Product, Cost, dbo.Product_Bucket_Type(Product) AS xyz...`

Comment: could you create a 2-column table with productcodes and bucketTypes?  Then you could join on the productCode field and the back end could enforce a PK constraint on productCode for you.

Comment: Personally, I strongly recommend @Beth's advice.  The code, as is, is not very maintainable.  Someone might add "22" to row 8, and it will be almost impossible to figure out that it never gets there, because it is in the first case statement.

Comment: @Hexxer, to improve the chances that you receive good answers in the future, you should not post a question and leave it unattended afterwards. If an answer was helpful, vote it up. If it solved your problem, mark it as accepted. If it wasn't helpful, comment it with the reasons as to why it didn't help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall form my brief comment into a proper answer for you.
To provide an immediate solution, you can change your stored procedure to a scalar-valued function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Product_Bucket_Type] (
    @productcode nvarchar(4)= NULL
) RETURNS nvarchar(30)
AS BEGIN   
    DECLARE @bucket nvarchar(30)
    Select
         @bucket = Case
         WHEN @productcode IN ('20','22', '26','27','28','2A','2B') THEN 'CA'
         ...
    RETURN @bucket
END
```

Now you can run your query as `SELECT Product, Cost, dbo.Product_Bucket_Type(Product) AS whatever FROM ...`

Better yet, you follow Beth's and Gordon's advice, and separate your codes out into 1 or 2 tables that you join your query on. Without proper knowledge of what your tables look like presently that is a bit hard to say - as a wild guess I'd put this (pseudo-structure) together:

> Table ProductCodes (ID, ProductCode)
> 1    '20'
> 2    '2XA'
> 3    '2XB'
> and so on
>
> Table BucketTypes (id, BucketType)
> 1    'CA'
> 2    'OU'

... (depending on 1:n, n:1 or n:m connections, which is hard to see, you may want something like this for n:m's

> TABLE ProductCodes_Link_BucketType (ProductCodes_ID, BucketTypes_ID)
> 1    1
> 2    2
> 3    2

Not sure what may fit your requirements, so I shall leave it at that. Hope it helps.